# Wordpress blank screen after uninstall plugin/ deleting post

Tags: wordpress

Using wordpress, but after some time use, when i deactivate/ativate plugin
or delete post, then white screen with text "Error is getting display".

After enabling the Debug, getting below message
Please help

> for constructors WP_Widget is since version 4.3.0 of date! Use instead
>   __construct () , in /var/www/vhosts/briefmich.de/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on
>   line 3457
>
> Notice: The used method for constructors WP_Widget is since version
>   4.3.0 of date! Use instead
>   __construct () , in /var/www/vhosts/briefmich.de/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on
>   line 3457
>
> Notice: The used method for constructors WP_Widget is since version
>   4.3.0 of date! Use instead
>   __construct () , in /var/www/vhosts/briefmich.de/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on
>   line 3457
>
> Notice: The used method for constructors WP_Widget is since version
>   4.3.0 of date! Use instead
>   __construct () , in /var/www/vhosts/briefmich.de/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on
>   line 3457
>
> Notice: The used method for constructors WP_Widget is since version
>   4.3.0 of date! Use instead
>   __construct () , in /var/www/vhosts/briefmich.de/httpdocs/wp-      includes/functions.php on
>   line 3457
>
> Notice: The used method for constructors WP_Widget is since version
>   4.3.0 of date! Use instead
>   __construct () , in /var/www/vhosts/briefmich.de/httpdocs/wp-      includes/functions.php on
>   line 3457

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('deprecated_constructor_trigger_error', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a recent change in WordPress to [deprecate PHP4 style constructors](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/02/deprecating-php4-style-constructors-in-wordpress-4-3/).  Most likely your theme or a plugin you are using is using the old constructor style for a widget that it is implementing.

You can try disabling plugins one by one until the error goes away or look for code in your functions/themes/plugins that extend the `WP_Widget` class and use `function` instead of `__construct` in the class code.